# Tomcat Server Hanging During Startup When Using Spring Rabbit

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am using spring rabbit 1.5.1 in one of my projects & I have some custom code which creates listener container objects on the fly during the startup (not in the configuration, but programmatically **via a bean**).
But the server never seem to comeup & hangs for ever.
When I took the thread dump, this is what I found out so far.

```
***"SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1" #38 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f84bf220000 nid=0x8503 waiting for monitor entry [0x000000012a583000]
java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:187)
- waiting to lock <0x00000007713d46b0> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:488)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:447)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:423)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:530)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:523)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1153)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.initialize(RabbitAdmin.java:384)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin$11.onCreate(RabbitAdmin.java:351)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CompositeConnectionListener.onCreate(CompositeConnectionListener.java:32)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:502)
- locked <0x0000000774662870> (a java.lang.Object)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$1.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:80)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:130)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.getTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:67)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:456)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1158)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)***
```

along with one more below:

```
***"SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1" #41 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f84bb162800 nid=0x8b03 waiting for monitor entry [0x0000000126e73000]
java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:498)
- waiting to lock <0x0000000774662870> (a java.lang.Object)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$1.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:80)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:130)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.getTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:67)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:456)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1158)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)***
```

I am not sure how to get over this problem. Looking forward for some inputs/directions to solve this.

Comment: Just an additional information that I noticed after I enabled debug logging in the spring was that the bean was initialized once earlier, after which the whole thing starts all over again when this problem came.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show your code; you say you're creating the containers programmatically, (outside of Spring), yet you are interacting with the application context via the `RabbitAdmin`.

You can't have it both ways; either use a context, or don't.

You need to find which thread owns this lock

```
waiting to lock <0x00000007713d46b0>
```

and you might be able to figure out a work-around.

One possibility would be to use a separate connection factory (created outside of a Spring application context) so the rabbit admin is not invoked to declare the queues etc.

Another way might be to disable `RabbitAdmin` auto declaration by setting `autoStartup` to false.

But, the first step is to find out who owns that lock.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Gary. I was trying to create a sample code to show this behaviour, but wasn't able to! I cannot show the code that I am writing (It's not public) & I hope you understand. I "do understand" the need for having the piece of code here. Nevertheless, your suggestion worked for me when I created a different connection factory. I will accept this as the answer as soon as I am done with few testing. Thanks once again.